# Making an upcoming / front page view in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal

I would like to make a site ala failblog.org where users submit content and vote on content

what I would like to do is

a. add a field to node / article called lets say 'front_page_at (date_time)'

b. every say 15 minutes calculate the average score for all nodes created in the last 48 hours and

c. set front_page_at = now for each node with score higher then this average.

so now I can have a view showing front_page_at is not null sorted desc for the front page
and front_page_at is null sorted by creation datetime for upcoming.

can anyone point me to how to achieve that ? where to run this averaging code etc ?

Answer (score 3):

You could do something approximating what you're looking for by starting with the [Voting API module](https://drupal.org/project/votingapi), in conjunction with on of the various voting module, such as [Fivestar](https://drupal.org/project/fivestar) or [Vote Up/Down](https://drupal.org/project/vote_up_down).

You could then use the [Views module](https://drupal.org/project/views) to create a view for your front page, which displays items newer than X number of days that reach a particular threshold.

If you have to have the averaging and scheduling, you may be able to do that using the [Rules module](https://drupal.org/project/rules). If not, you may need to write a custom module for that.

Comment: But I would like the items to be sorted by the time they were promoted so I need to add a field to the node module, the front_page_at field. How do I do that ?

Comment: You can probably do that using the Date Updated field on the node.